# Why wouldn't this QUERY work when comparing multiple %'s in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The cells referenced contain `0,1`, `0,25`, `0,5`, `0,75` and the column `T` where there data sits do have  `0,1`, `0,25`, `0,5`, `0,75`, which look identical, but nothing gets returned and I wonder what I may be missing here.
`=QUERY(Dados!A1:V;"select A, B, E, L, ' ', M, N, O, G, F, P, Q, R, T, I, J where T matches '"&G5&"|"&H5&"|"&J5&"|"&K5&"|"&L5&"|"&M5&"|"&N5&"' label ' ' ' '")`

Here is the practical example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an [*alternate approach*](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit#gid=1786550278) using `filter()` and `no helper cells`

```
=filter(J:K;xmatch(K:K;filter(B1:H1;B2:H2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Please be careful. Choosing `0%` you run into problems. I believe the formula should be improved as follows: `=filter(J:K;xmatch(K:K;filter(B1:H1;B2:H2));K:K<>"")`

Answer (score 1):

Your QUERY formula is correct. The key notion here is: *"...**which look identical**..."*.
I believe (since no actual data has been provided) that either your data in column `T` or in row `5` are results of calculations **formatted to 2 decimals**.

If this is the case, `0,25` is NOT equal/the same as `0,25000001`. Once formatted they may look the same but are not.

If this is not the case, please share a test sheet.

Comment: Just added an example above. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @onit I guess I was late for the party :)  Still. **Be careful with the accepted answer**. If you try your `0%` values, you will run into problems. To avoid them, improve the formula as follows: `=filter(J:K;xmatch(K:K;filter(B1:H1;B2:H2));K:K<>"")`

Comment: Thanks! The data will be entered as data validation that chance is close to zero. Thanks a lot for the suggested improvement, though.